# Is there a GEM for HTML parsing in Ruby, like Cheerio in NodeJS?

Tags: ruby, node.js, rubygems, cheerio, html-parser

Is there a Ruby GEM available for HTML parsing, like Cheerio in NodeJS? Cheerio is an easy to use HTML parser, works like jQuery.

Comment: There are about a dozen, actually.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is.

It's called Nokogiri: http://www.nokogiri.org/

Comment: Nokogiri is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate NodeJS Cheerio in ruby, with the help of Nokogiri.

gem name:

> ruby-cheerio

Please find a sample code on the below link.

[sample code](https://github.com/dineshsprabu/ruby-cheerio/blob/master/sample_code/get_gem_info.rb)